# In how many ways i can write 12?

Tags: combinatorics, integer-partitions

In how many ways i can write 12 as an ordered sum of integers where
the smallest of that integers is 2? for example 2+10 ; 10+2 ; 2+5+2+3 ; 5+2+2+3;
2+2+2+2+2+2;2+4+6; and many more

Comment: Why is the question mark after your statement "The smallest of that integers is 2"?

Comment: @srijan I think it is supposed to be the end of the first sentence.

Comment: @user1 I think so.

Comment: Why are you talking about "order" if you say both "2+10" and "10+2" are ok ? I guess what you mean by ordered is that you want to find a set of integers $(a_i)_{i\in[1,n]}$ where $\cases{a_1=2 \\ a_1 \leq a_2 \leq ... \leq a_n \\ a_1+...+a_n=12}$

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory)

Comment: @Dolma: No, he does mean [ordered sums](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_(number_theory)), counting "2+10" and "10+2" are distinct. The "ordered" doesn't mean that the terms within a particular sum are in sorted order, but just that their order is relevant.

Comment: @ShreevatsaR: Yes I realized this a few minutes after posting my comment.

Comment: Btw if your consider only partitions (order not relevent) then the answer is p(12)-p(11). For a proof see: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/356104/related-to-the-partition-of-n-where-pn-2-denotes-the-number-of-partitions

Answer (score 9):

There are $89$ ways (and $89$ is the $11$th Fibonacci number).

---

You're looking for "restricted [compositions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_%28number_theory%29)" of $12$ (the restriction being that each part is at least $2$).

In [Sage](http://sagemath.org/) ([doc](http://www.sagemath.org/doc/reference/combinat/sage/combinat/composition.html#sage.combinat.composition.Compositions)):

```
sage: Compositions(12, min_part = 2).list()
[[12], [10, 2], [9, 3], [8, 4], [8, 2, 2], [7, 5], [7, 3, 2], [7, 2, 3], [6, 6], [6, 4, 2], [6, 3, 3], [6, 2, 4], [6, 2, 2, 2], [5, 7], [5, 5, 2], [5, 4, 3], [5, 3, 4], [5, 3, 2, 2], [5, 2, 5], [5, 2, 3, 2], [5, 2, 2, 3], [4, 8], [4, 6, 2], [4, 5, 3], [4, 4, 4], [4, 4, 2, 2], [4, 3, 5], [4, 3, 3, 2], [4, 3, 2, 3], [4, 2, 6], [4, 2, 4, 2], [4, 2, 3, 3], [4, 2, 2, 4], [4, 2, 2, 2, 2], [3, 9], [3, 7, 2], [3, 6, 3], [3, 5, 4], [3, 5, 2, 2], [3, 4, 5], [3, 4, 3, 2], [3, 4, 2, 3], [3, 3, 6], [3, 3, 4, 2], [3, 3, 3, 3], [3, 3, 2, 4], [3, 3, 2, 2, 2], [3, 2, 7], [3, 2, 5, 2], [3, 2, 4, 3], [3, 2, 3, 4], [3, 2, 3, 2, 2], [3, 2, 2, 5], [3, 2, 2, 3, 2], [3, 2, 2, 2, 3], [2, 10], [2, 8, 2], [2, 7, 3], [2, 6, 4], [2, 6, 2, 2], [2, 5, 5], [2, 5, 3, 2], [2, 5, 2, 3], [2, 4, 6], [2, 4, 4, 2], [2, 4, 3, 3], [2, 4, 2, 4], [2, 4, 2, 2, 2], [2, 3, 7], [2, 3, 5, 2], [2, 3, 4, 3], [2, 3, 3, 4], [2, 3, 3, 2, 2], [2, 3, 2, 5], [2, 3, 2, 3, 2], [2, 3, 2, 2, 3], [2, 2, 8], [2, 2, 6, 2], [2, 2, 5, 3], [2, 2, 4, 4], [2, 2, 4, 2, 2], [2, 2, 3, 5], [2, 2, 3, 3, 2], [2, 2, 3, 2, 3], [2, 2, 2, 6], [2, 2, 2, 4, 2], [2, 2, 2, 3, 3], [2, 2, 2, 2, 4], [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2]]
sage: Compositions(12, min_part = 2).cardinality()
89
```

---

The number for general $n$ in place of $12$ would be interesting to calculate. Using Sage again:

```
sage: print ','.join(str(Compositions(n, min_part = 2).cardinality()) for n in range(20))
1,0,1,1,2,3,5,8,13,21,34,55,89,144,233,377,610,987,1597,2584
```

[Searching for that on OEIS](http://oeis.org/search?q=1%2C0%2C1%2C1%2C2%2C3%2C5%2C8%2C13%2C21%2C34%2C55%2C89%2C144%2C233%2C377%2C610%2C987%2C1597%2C2584&language=english&go=Search) gives [A212804](http://oeis.org/A212804) as the sequence.

This of course is the Fibonacci sequence with an additional "1" at the beginning.

---

Now it would be interesting to prove that it is so for general $n$. This is easy now that we know what to prove. Let's call compositions with each part at least $2$ as "good" compositions. Let $C_n$ be the number of "good" compositions of $n$. Any such "good" composition either begins with $2$ or with a number greater than 2:

- If it starts with $2$, then it can be got by prepending a $2$ to a "good" composition of $n-2$ (and there are $C_{n-2}$ of them)
- If it starts with a number greater than $2$, then it can be got by taking a "good" composition of $n-1$ (there are $C_{n-1}$ of them) and incrementing the first element by one.

So $C_n = C_{n-2} + C_{n-1}$, which along with the initial conditions $C_0 = 1$ and $C_1 = 0$, proves what we wanted to prove.

Comment: I've added "with each part at least $2$" to both points at the end, since this was clearly intended

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen: Thanks, that was indeed intended.

Comment: @ShreevatsaR, great answer!

Comment: look at my new answer

Answer (score 5):

You are looking for number of partitions of 12 in parts greater than 1. Because their number is not so big we can present all of them in a list bellow
$$\begin{array}{c|c}
2+2+2+2+2+2 & 1 \\
2+2+2+2+4 &  5 \\
2+2+2+3+3 &  10 \\
2+2+2+6 &  4 \\
2+2+3+5 & 12 \\
2+2+4+4 & 6 \\
2+3+3+4 & 12 \\
3+3+3+3 & 1 \\
2+2+8 & 3 \\
2+3+7 & 6 \\
2+4+6 & 6 \\
2+5+5 & 3 \\
3+3+6 & 3 \\
3+4+5 & 6 \\
4+4+4 & 1 \\
2+10 & 2 \\
3+9 & 2 \\
4+8 & 2 \\
5+7 & 2 \\
6+6 & 1 \\
12 & 1 \\
\end{array}$$
The partition turn in composition if we rearrange them. Number of arrangements is given on the right, so total number of compositions is $89$

Comment: I've edited the post to use array (thought it looks nicer); feel free to rollback if you don't like it.

Comment: Thank you. Now it look better

Answer (score 3):

Following answer is for general case.
Denote by $c_m(1,n)=\binom{n-1}{m-1}$ the number of composition of $n$ into $m$ positive parts, and by $c_m(2,n)$ number of compositions of $n$ into $m$ parts greater than $1$. 
Each composition of $n$ into $m$ parts greater than $1$, if all parts decrease by 1, becomes a composition of $n-m$ into $m$ positive parts. That means $$c_m(2,n)=c_m(1,n-m)=\binom{n-m-1}{m-1}$$
Number of all compositions of $n$ into parts greater than $1$ is $$c(2,n)=\sum_{m=1}^{n}c_m(2,n)=\sum_{m=1}^{n}\binom{n-m-1}{m-1}$$
In our case $n=12$
$$c(2,12)=\sum_{m=1}^{12}\binom{11-m}{m-1}=\sum_{m=1}^{6}\binom{11-m}{m-1}=$$
$$=\binom{10}{0}+\binom{9}{1}+\binom{8}{2}+\binom{7}{3}+\binom{6}{4}+\binom{5}{5}=$$
$$1+9+28+35+15+1=89$$

Comment: I think the final expression is too complicated: if you can prove that $\sum_{m=1}^n\binom{n-m-1}{m-1} = F_{n-1}$, then that would be cool. But this is a nice solution, +1.

Comment: For such proof you can see at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/297443/prove-the-following-equality-sum-k-0n-binom-n-k-k-f-n/297490#297490

Answer (score 1):

Let's split the question into a few pieces.

**First part**: how many ways to sum if all numbers are even? In this case, it's a simple partition problem, and the answer is equally simple. If you imagine the digits like this:

..|..|..|..|..|.. = 2+2+2+2+2+2

Then each of the five dividers can either be there or not, giving exactly $2^5=32$ ways of summing when they're all even.

**Second part**: Having the odd part summing to six, how many ways? In this case, there's just 3+3, and then you place three 2s and two 3s, which is equivalent to choosing two places in a sequence of five to place the 3s. But you can also place a 2 and a 4, a 4 and a 2, or a 6. So that's $\binom{5}{2}+2\binom{4}{2}+\binom{3}{2}=10+2\cdot6+3=25$. So far, we have 57.

**Third part**: Having the odd part summing to eight, how many ways? In this case, there's 3+5 and 5+3, and either two 2s or a 4. So that's $2\binom{4}{2}+2\binom{3}{2}=2\cdot 6+2\cdot 3 = 18$. We're up to 75.

**Fourth part**: Having the odd part summing to ten, how many ways? In this case, there's 3+7, 5+5, and 7+3, and then a 2 in each case. So there's three ways of placing the 2, and then three ways of choosing the remaining number pair, for a total of 9. That brings us to 84.

**Final part**: Having the odd part summing to twelve, how many ways? In this case, it's easiest to count - there's 3+3+3+3, 3+9, 5+7, 7+5, and 9+3, for a total of 5. So our answer is 89.

Answer (score 1):

All the posted answers are answering the following variation of the original question:
"In how many ways i can write 12 as an ordered sum of integers where the smallest of those integers is **at least** 2?". But, the question asks the count when the smallest of the integers is equal to 2, so all the posted answers are over-counting (polite way to say that they are incorrect) -- for example, 3+4+5 or 6+6 are not valid compositions since the smallest integer is 3 and 6, respectively, in these examples, not 2. Discounting such compositions from Adi Dani's enumerative solution above, I get 70.